# How to get values from a csv file without expected CSV column headers

Tags: php, laravel-5, fgetcsv, maatwebsite-excel

A user prepares a CSV file for upload. The only mandatory and expected CSV column headers are `title` and `description`.

However, the user can have other personal CSV columns headers of their choice. That is, apart from the two mandatory ones `title` and `description` a user can opt to include another say `remarks` `time` e.t.c.

I would want to get the extra data in all of these other columns altogether (if they exist) and save as an array in one database field `data`.

However, I can not think of a way to get the extra field data. See below

```
if($request->hasFile('import_file')){
    $path = $request->file('import_file')->getRealPath();
    $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {})->get();
    if(!empty($data) && $data->count()){
        foreach ($data->toArray() as $key => $value) {
            if(!empty($value)){
                foreach ($value as $v) {        
                    $insert[] = ['title' => $v['title'], 'description' => $v['description'], ['data' => $v['xxxxxxxxxxxx'], ];
                }
            }
        }
        if(!empty($insert)){
            Item::insert($insert);
            return back()->with('success','Insert Record successfully.');
        }
    }
}
return back()->with('error','Please Check your file, Something is wrong there.');
```

How do I get this extra data that is optional and save it as well?

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your requirement is to take all the columns from the array, except title and description and merge/jsonify them and store it. If this is what you wanted

```
$insert = []; //just to be safe declare $insert here 
foreach ($data->toArray() as $key => $value) {
  if(!empty($value)){
     foreach ($value as $v) {        
        $insert[] = [
           'title' => $v['title'], 
           'description' => $v['description'], 
           'data' => array_except($v,['title', 'description']),//maybe you want to jsonify or merge data 
        ];
     }
  }
}
//DB insertion logic
```

You can read about the `array_except()` helper function [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-array-except)

Answer (score 0):

You could store it in JSON...

```
foreach ($value as $v) {   
    $data = json_encode($v);     
    $insert[] = ['title' => $v['title'], 'description' => $v['description'], 'data' => $data ];
}
```

This includes the title and description, you could create a new array without that data and then store it if you wanted.